# Как правильно записать алгоритм на JS

Tags: javascript

подскажите как правильно записать алгоритм без переменной 'pro'.

```
let j = 0,
        pro = true,
        len_j = this.multi.length;
        for(;len_j>j;j++){
           if(this.multi[j].key){
              pro = false;
              break;
           }
        }
        if(pro){
          this.multi.push({name:"Показать все", series:[]})
        }
```

Comment: а что за алгоритм-то? что он делает?

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном коде проверяется наличие в массиве элемента, с определенным значением ключа.

Для проверки можно использовать метод [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Например:

```
if(!this.multi.some(el=>el.key)){
    this.multi.push({name:"Показать все", series:[]});
}
```